# jenkins shuts down upon logoff from ssh session

Tags: openssl, jenkins

I have setup two instances where (1) is running httpd to reverse proxy. (2) is running jenkins.war.

```
[1st instance - ssl.conf]
#ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://secondinstance:8081/ nocanon
#ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://secondinstance:8081/

[2nd instance - jenkins.war]
sudo java -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --httpsPort=8081 is invoked to listen on 8081.
```

I can use the first instance's https address to access the jenkins instance.

However, whenever I terminate the SSH session on my 2nd instance, the jenkins shuts down prematurely.

How do I make jenkins be on persistently? 
Without having to have the 2nd instance ssh session on.

I couldn't find any information on the search engines relevant to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `init.d`' script to start your `Jenkins`, you can find more information at:

[Installing Jenkins as a Unix daemon - Jenkins - Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JenkinsLinuxStartupScript)

```
# service jenkins status
jenkins (pid  1386) is running...
#
```

or you can always use `nohup` if `init.d` is not an option.